# This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: google-analytics

I have been building some GATC tags for a newsletter campaign. When I set the tag as

http://www.eafs.eu/index.php?utm_campaign=powermta1&utm_content=introduction&utm_medium=email&utm_source=news1

on clicking the links it has been changed to

http://www.eafs.eu**/?lang=en&**utm_campaign=powermta1&utm_content=introduction&utm_medium=email&utm_source=news1

A message in Chrome come up using the debugger.

This webpage has a redirect loop

I have cleared the cache and tested on other browsers and although no error the page now goes to a 404 page.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

This seem to be an issue with sh404SEF and Joomla 2.5. The Joomla settings Search Engine Friendly URLs & Use URL rewriting were turned off for some treason so turned them back on and all working again. Redirect loop has now been closed.